# Displaying images one after another, with a blank screen in between, using different time durations

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set something up using javascript that displays a series of images, say you have 10 images, where each one is displayed for 1 second, and in between each image you have a blank white screen displayed for half a second.

so something like `(image_1, 1 sec) -> (white screen .5 sec) -> (image_2, 1 sec) -> (white screen .5 sec)....until all the images have been displayed`.

I've found useful code here:

http://menditknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2012/10/display-series-of-images-one-after.html

and here:

[How to display images one at a time through loop with HTML/Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318109/how-to-display-images-one-at-a-time-through-loop-with-html-javascript)

But they only display images one after another.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with the [Cycle2](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/) plugin

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.tile.js"></script>

    <div class="cycle-slideshow" 
        data-cycle-timeout=0
        data-cycle-next="#next5"
        data-cycle-prev="#prev5"
        >
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p1.jpg" data-cycle-fx=tileSlide data-cycle-tile-vertical=false>
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p2.jpg" data-cycle-fx=tileBlind data-cycle-tile-count=12>
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p3.jpg" data-cycle-fx=tileSlide data-cycle-tile-count=4>
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p4.jpg" data-cycle-fx=tileBlind data-cycle-tile-vertical=false>
    </div>
```